# how fastcgi close the connection between client and nginx

Tags: nginx, lua, fastcgi, connection-close

My application tructure is client ->nginx(keepalive open) -> fastcgi, and I need fastcgi control the connection close or keep-live. I tried to close the connection between clinet and nginx by these 2 attempt.

1. by return response header Connection:close, but still get Connection:keep-alive on client(ngx return)
2. I tried lua module in header_filter_lua, not work either
   set Connection=close: client get two Connection header keep-alive and close both
   return ngx.exit(): ngx return keep-alive and then return Fin to close the connection, but neither body nor fastcgi headers were return

any anther method?